# How to return error immediately in Spring Reactive Mongo?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

I was testing some error handling when saving a document to mongodb. To trigger the error, I stopped the mongo server after spring had started successfully. Then I sent the request to save a document.

Shortly after the code fails because it cannot connect to the mongo server, but the request takes 65+ seconds to return the error in postman.

Is there a way to return the error immediatley after the exception is thrown? e.g. `ConnectException`

**My current code to handle save errors:**

```
return myRepository
    .save(doc)
    .map { ResponseEntity(mapOf(Pair("id", it.id)), HttpStatus.OK) }
    .onErrorReturn( ResponseEntity(emptyMap(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
```

[image: postman image showing 65+ second loading time]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that the timeout is at mongo level you can't override it only for your endpoint, but you can introduce another timeout in your reactive pipeline like below:

```
return myRepository
.save(doc)
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.onErrorReturn( ResponseEntity(emptyMap(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
.map { ResponseEntity(mapOf(Pair("id", it.id)), HttpStatus.OK) }
```

Pay attention!!!!
 the introduced timeout solve your problem of return fast the error but the underline mongo connection is pending yet until it reach the mongo timeout. probably a better choice may be of tuning the default mongo connection timeout and use a reactive pipeline for let free soon the web server threads.

I hope that it can help you

Comment: thanks for the short-term solution :) Will investigate setting timeouts at the mongo level next :)